# Require annotated tags and reject lightweight tags on git push

Tags: git, git-tag

Is it possible to set up a policy on a git repo that disallows lightweight tags from being pushed to it?

Comment: The [`update.sample`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=templates/hooks--update.sample;h=71ab04edc09be7aeefa1e8a0f609a974ffd55a9f;hb=HEAD) hook that Git automatically installs into new repositories includes this exact functionality (among a few other useful bits). Take a look at `$GIT_DIR/hooks/update.sample` any of your existing repositories.

Answer (score 4):

The [Git hook page](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) mentions:

> The default update hook, when enabled — and with **`hooks.allowunannotated`** config option unset or set to false — prevents unannotated tags to be pushed.

That references in turn the [`update.sample`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=templates/hooks--update.sample;h=71ab04edc09be7aeefa1e8a0f609a974ffd55a9f;hb=HEAD) [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen) mentions in the comments.

```
case "$refname","$newrev_type" in
    refs/tags/*,commit)
        # un-annotated tag
        short_refname=${refname##refs/tags/}
        if [ "$allowunannotated" != "true" ]; then
            echo "*** The un-annotated tag, $short_refname, is not allowed in this repository" >&2
            echo "*** Use 'git tag [ -a | -s ]' for tags you want to propagate." >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

The update hook is invoked on the receiving (remote) repository from the perspective of `git push`. Sometimes, you do not have access to install hooks on remote repositories; as far as I know, this is the case for GitHub (which happily allows pushing lightweight tags).

To prevent lightweight tags from being pushed from the local repository, you could add this to the body of the reading loop in `.git/hooks/pre-push`, as copied from `pre-push.sample`:

```
case "$local_ref" in
    refs/tags/*)
        if [ `git cat-file -t "$local_ref"` == 'commit' ]
        then
            echo >&2 "Tag $local_ref is not annotated, not pushing"
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

However, the best solution in my opinion is to sidestep the whole problem.
Annotated tags can be pushed automatically together with any refs from which these tags are reachable. Configuration variable `push.followTags` enables this behavior, so you can do the right thing by default and hardly ever have to push tags explicitly:

```
git config --global push.followTags true
```